# Use different versions of a program in different directories

Tags: software-installation, cmake

I am accessing a server remotely and do not have sudo privileges. To get my work done I need to have a newer version of cmake. The admin will not update cmake globally so I need it to work in my directory only. I have downloaded the source files and compiled them as instructed with a new prefix:

```
./bootstrap --prefix=/home/myDirectory/myCMakeDirectory
make
make install
```

I have also used ./configure in place of bootstrap. However, the cmake command still uses the old version of cmake that is installed globally when I try to use it. i.e,

```
cmake --version
```

returns the old version (cmake-2.6.4). How can I install cmake locally so that the cmake command uses my version. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added `/home/myDirectory/myCMakeDirectory/bin` to the front of your `PATH` ?

Comment: `PATH` is an environment variable, it contains a list of directories to search (in order), for executables. Each entry is separated by a `:`. You need to add the directory containing `cmake` to this list, in addition it must come earlier in the list than the existing system directory containing `cmake` (put it at the beginning of the list).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your `PATH` to include `/home/myDirectory/myCMakeDirectory/bin` before the default directories.

In `sh` shells:

```
PATH="/home/myDirectory/myCMakeDirectory/bin:$PATH"
```

This would go in your shell init scripts (`.bashrc` for example).

I would also recommend using [GNU Stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) for private software installations from source, and to do them with prefix `$HOME/local/stow` or something similar.

Comment: This works! I added that line to .bash_profile. Thanks a million. Have been getting kicked by this for awhile now.